# webgl cannot draw too many primitives in one drawcall on integrated graphics card

Tags: performance, gpu, webgl, rendering

I am recently testing my webgl render engine.
I just found a interesting thing.
So if I am drawing 20 million of triangles on my integrated graphics card.
If I render it in 500 drawcalls (40,000 per drawcall), maybe some drawcall are more than 40k, some are less. The FPS is only like 4-5
However, if I render it in 1500 drawcalls, (13,333 faces per drawcall), it could magically reach 11

Then I tried to run this on a discrete graphics, the result just reversed, the 500 drawcall is directly 60FPS, but the 1500 drawcall is slower.

So I am wondering why and is it because the integrated graphics card can not process such a big data in one drawcall?
How does it works?

Thanks a huge

Comment: which gpus are you testing with and how are you testing?

Comment: i used two computers one uses intel(R) HD Graphics 630, the other uses Nivdia 980Ti
and i just run two models(500 drawcalls and 1500 drawcalls with same amount of triangle faces) in each computer.
the cpu and memory should not be a problem because the main difference is on intel card the 500drawcall model is slower than the 1500drawcalls.
but on nvidia the 500drawcall is faster. So i am thinking if it's the problem with the graphics card can not deal with too many faces in one single drawcall, might be a cache issue or something. just want to know why